# What approach to choose when refactoring method, so that it responds to the principles of clean code?

Tags: java, methods, refactoring, parameter-passing, clean-architecture

I have this method signature:

```
public User getActiveUser(String personId, User mainUser) throws MyExceptions {

    if (personId== null) return mainUser;

        User innerUser = userRepository.getByPersonId(personId);

        checkForNull(innerUser);
        checkIsActive(innerUser);

        return innerUser;

 }

    private void checkForNull(User innerUser) throws UNPExceptions {
        if (innerUser == null) throw new MyExceptions(USER_NOT_FOUND);
    }

    private void checkIsActive(User innerUser) throws UNPExceptions {
        if (!innerUser.getIsActive()) throw new MyExceptions(USER_BLOCKED);
    }
```

And I call this method from different places like this:

```
User user = userService.getActive(userRequest.getPersonId(), requestEntity.getUser());
```

I do not like this code because:

1) I pass 2 parameters to this method `getActiveUser(String personId, User mainUser)`

`mainUser` always return if `personId` is null. I can move this check inside method but then I have to do it every time before calling the method. And the method is called from many places. so I moved the check to one place. But it looks crooked and I do not know how to get around it. I don’t want to pass the second parameter just to do this check inside the method, but it looks better than copying this check before each method call. I do not know which solution is better. maybe there is another solution.

2) method name - `getActiveUser` is lying. because inside I do more checks. but I do not know how to call it - `getActiveUserAndCheck`? this is also not correct as the method is responsible for several duties

3) Is it necessary to divide checks into separate methods? `checkForNull(innerUser);
 checkIsActive(innerUser);`

Answer (score 0):

Using Java8+, you can simply replace

```
checkForNull(innerUser);
checkIsActive(innerUser);
return innerUser;
```

by means of [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html), as:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(innerUser)
               .filter(User::getIsActive)
               .orElseThrow(() -> new MyExceptions(""));
```

---

If you want to default to `mainUser`, you could do something on these lines(just that this is not throwing your custom exception) :

```
return Optional.ofNullable(personId) // check for person 'null'
               .map(p -> userRepository.getByPersonId(personId)) if present evaluate 'innerUser'
               .filter(Objects::nonNull) // check if innerUser is null
               .filter(User::getIsActive) // check if innerUser is active
               .orElse(defaultUser); if any of above fails return defaultUser
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. But I am disturbed more by the second parameter in a method. I don’t know how correctly I do when I pass it to the method just to return if the first parameter is NULL

Comment: and I can not throw `MyExeption extends Exception` with  `public <X extends Throwable> T orElseThrow(Supplier<? extends X> exceptionSupplier) throws X {`

Comment: @ip696 The second parameter, you mean `mainUser` ? But there is no check in your code against that.

Comment: Yes mainUser. I mean this check - `if (personId== null) return mainUser;` I pass it only to return if the first parameter is null

Comment: @ip696 so its ideally a `defaultUser`, right? And what's the harm with returning that?

Comment: I see no harm in returning it. But I don’t like what I pass it. And regarding your example with optional - this is really beautiful, but there is still a problem - if null I need throw  is one exception and if not active then the other

Comment: @ip696 Updated with a similar approach you could follow. Note: the syntax within those Optional APIs might not be exact as I've used the syntax from the question just to try and map.

Comment: Passing in a default value if the first argument does not match is a very common and useful pattern. It moves the boilerplate into one shared method rather than every caller. Take a look at System.getProperty(String key, String defaultIfMissing);

Comment: @Rich MacDonald Is there a name for this pattern?

Comment: I've never come across a name for this. Guess it was too obvious for something to think it worth an academic paper :-)

Answer (score 0):

If the mainUser is always the same user you don't have to pass it as a method parameter, you can store it as an instance field and initialize it when appropriate.

If that's not the case, you can use AOP to handle the case with null personId and the aspect component will be responsible for retrieving the mainUser.